# iOS Update JSON objects

Tags: ios, json, sqlite

I've come across an existing iOS app. It downloads JSON from a web service and, at runtime, parses the JSON into Map Annotation objects to show on a map.
This is relatively fast as there's only about 2000 records.

The problem is that I now want to update/delete records by asking for the "updated since [date]" records. When I get these records I have no idea how I'm going to update the JSON.

I feel like one of the only options might be to store the objects into SQLite or something similar before I create the map points. So then updates will be done to the SQLite records, and I can just re-create the annotations.

Has anyone got a better idea? I'd like to stay with the original JSON only approach if possible

Comment: Parse the JSON to a data structure, delete from the data structure, then serialize it back to JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Data would be the best way to go in my opinion.

Storing a large amount of records in a plist or plain JSON just isn't a good idea in the long run. With Core Data you can easily fetch records, update and delete records as needed. Once you have updated your data you can re-fetch and update the map with the annotation.

You should look into MagicalRecord which can assist with mapping the data to NSManagedObjects.

For example, take this JSON:

```
result: [
        { longitude: ...,
          latitude: ...,
          locationName: ...
        },
        { longitude: ...,
          latitude: ...,
          locationName: ...
        }
        ],
 status: "ok"
```

You can create an NSManagedObject with the following attributes:

```
MyLocationObject:
longitude (double)
latitude (double)
locationName (string)
```

Then, with MagicalRecord you simple do the following to parse and save the objects:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
     // loop through all the locations
     for (NSDictionary *locationDictionary in [response objectForKey:@"result"]) {
         // first we will do a fetch in the database to see if we already have the object
         // I am using the location name as a reference but if you have a unique ID in the JSON, use that instead
         MyLocationObject *locationObject = [MyLocationObject findFirstByAttribute:@"locationName" withValue:[locationDictionary objectForKey:@"locationName"];
         // if locationObject is nil we need to create a new record
         if (!locationObject) {
             locationObject = [MyLocationObject createInContext:localContext];
         }
         // now simple map the JSON to the object
         [locationObject importValuesForKeysWithObject:locationDictionary];
     }
}];
```

You can use something like AFNetworking which will automatically parse the JSON response to the appropriate NSObject (dictionary/array) for your use.

Comment: Good answer. This seems like the best way to continue if I decide to do a new refactor. For the moment, we are sticking to weekly updates of the entire data, but on WiFi only.

If I have time later I will implement it into Core Data

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use creation/modification date of your local JSON copy and when parsing new JSON just ignore older records ? This is the approach I used in several apps for both JSON and XML data feeds and it always works like a ccharm